# 404 Not Found nginx/1.12.0

Tags: php, android, push-notification

Estou com grande problema que não tenho ideia o que pode ser.

Faço envio de notificações PUSH alguns APPS, funcional normalmente mas um APP em especifico que tem muitos usuários está dando o seguinte erro.

A chamada no GCM é a seguinte:

```
$url    = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
$fields = array(
    'data' => array(
        "mensagem" => $message
    ),
    'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids
);
if (is_array($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $fields['data'][$key] = $value;
    }
}

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch      = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
```

404 Not Found Nginx/1.12.0

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: "... que tem muitos usuários"? Como assim? Você usa esse código em vários apps, porém em um app específico não funciona?! Você teria que dar mais detalhes do problema.

Comment: Olá amigo, funciona assim: Tenho uma painel PUSH onde escolho o app para mandar o push, todos os apps funcionam porém eu tenho um APP que tem mais de 100 mil usuários, o serviço de PUSH GCM precisa ser enviado a cada 1000 usuários, então eu tenho um laço de repetição que fica mandando as notificações de 1000 em 1000 quando está perto do FIM ele me apresenta essa mensagem 404 Not Found Nginx/1.12.0

Comment: Acredito que possa ser o tempo em que está sendo processado  pagina PHP e está demorando a responder uma requisição AJAX.

Comment: Talvez um possível problema de timeout então. Não vi ninguém relatar isso aqui.

Comment: Só que não sei se o problema está no google(GCM), na pagina PHP que faz a integração com serviço do google ou meu código ajax que faz a requisição para a pagina PHP.

Comment: Porque você não tenta migrar para o FCM? Na pagina do GCM tem até um aviso sobre isso https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/